# Buiding iOS app from Xamarin Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am an iOS developer & I have to start work on Xamarin platform project for iOS. So I have some basic queries as a beginner in Xamarin. I have already initiated study from [Link1](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/) [Link2](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/)

App is developed in Android On Xamarin & now I have to develop the same app for iOS(iPhone+iPad).

So my question are

1. Can I reuse the C# code written for Android app in iOS?
2. I have to redesign the UI for iOS devices? (As per my knowledge "YES" plz
   confirm if I am wrong)

.Any idea or any suggestion would be great for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends.

If you had been using [`Xamarin.Forms`](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) you would only need to build one project which would then compile into a `.apk` (Android) and `.ipa` (iOS) distribution binary. Thus, by choosing Forms, you would only need to design and build the UI once as logic and UI is shared between all platforms.

On the other hand, you can chose to build your application using `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS`. In doing so, you can share the logic (e.g. `ViewModels`, `Services`, `Converters`) only. The rest will have to be built platform specific. So in the ladder case, you wouldn't be able to reuse the C# code which you've built for Android on iOS, as the platforms differ.

Comment: Thanks @Demitrian for answer. So in case, If I am not using the forms then can I use Android C# code for iOS? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Spot on, @Gagan_iOS. The `iOS` and `Android` `APIs` differ significantly, so you would need to implement the `Views` for both platforms,

Answer (score 1):

As Demitrian said earlier, using Xamarin.Forms allows you to build a single project.

If you want to use Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, which I do, you can build a solution containing an Android project and an iOS project, then add a Shared Project to your solution containing the common code, like classes, models, HTTP actions, etc. That way, you can save some programming time, while still taking advantage of each platform's specificities.